# How to show background bitmap on 2D

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

The background original bitmap and the real effect like this:

[image] [image]

This is my first time use Opengl ES 2.0. I don't know why and where my the problem is. Maybe some wrong happens in direction. My code:

```
public class BackgroundGLRnder implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer
{
    // Our matrices
    private final float[] mtrxProjection = new float[16];
    private final float[] mtrxView = new float[16];
    private final float[] mtrxProjectionAndView = new float[16];

    // Geometric variables
    private  float vertices[];
    private static float  uvs[] = new float[] {
        0.0f, 0.0f,
        0.0f, 1.0f,
        1.0f, 1.0f,
        1.0f, 0.0f
    };
    private static short indices[] = new short[]{ 0,  1,  2,  0,  2,  3};


    private FloatBuffer vertexBuffer;
    private ShortBuffer drawListBuffer;
    private FloatBuffer uvBuffer;

    // Our screenresolution
    private float   mScreenWidth = 1280;
    private float   mScreenHeight = 768;

    // Misc
    private Context mContext;
    private int mProgramHandle;
    private int mTextureDataHandle0;

    /** This will be used to pass in the transformation matrix. */
    private int mMVPMatrixHandle;

    /** This will be used to pass in the texture. */
    private int mTextureUniformHandle0;

    /** This will be used to pass in model position information. */
    private int mPositionHandle;

    /** This will be used to pass in model color information. */
    // private int mColorHandle;

    /** This will be used to pass in model texture coordinate information. */
    private int mTextureCoordinateHandle;

    public BackgroundGLRnder(Context c)
    {
        mContext = c;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config)
    {
        SetupImage();
        // Set the clear color to black
        GLES20.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1);

        final String vertexShader = getVertexShader();
        final String fragmentShader = getFragmentShader();

        final int vertexShaderHandle = ShaderHelper.compileShader(
            GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER,
            vertexShader);
        final int fragmentShaderHandle = ShaderHelper.compileShader(
            GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragmentShader);

        mProgramHandle = ShaderHelper.createAndLinkProgram(
            vertexShaderHandle,
            fragmentShaderHandle, new String[] { 
                    "a_Position",
                    "a_TexCoordinate" });

        // Set our per-vertex lighting program.
        GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgramHandle);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height)
    {
        mScreenWidth = width;
        mScreenHeight = height;

        // Redo the Viewport, making it fullscreen.
        GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, (int) mScreenWidth, (int) mScreenHeight);

        // Clear our matrices
        for(int i=0;i<16;i++)
        {
            mtrxProjection[i] = 0.0f;
            mtrxView[i] = 0.0f;
            mtrxProjectionAndView[i] = 0.0f;
        }

        // Setup our screen width and height for normal sprite translation.
        Matrix.orthoM(mtrxProjection, 0, 0f, mScreenWidth, 0.0f,     mScreenHeight, -1, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl)
    {
        // Set program handles for cube drawing.
        mMVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgramHandle,
            "u_MVPMatrix");
        mTextureUniformHandle0 = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgramHandle,
            "u_Texture");
        mPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgramHandle,     "a_Position");
        mTextureCoordinateHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgramHandle,
            "a_TexCoordinate");

        // clear Screen and Depth Buffer,
        // we have set the clear color as black.
        GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        GLES20.glBlendFunc(GLES20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GLES20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mTextureCoordinateHandle);

        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mPositionHandle, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, vertexBuffer);
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mTextureCoordinateHandle, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0,
            uvBuffer);


        // Apply the projection and view transformation
        GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mtrxProjection, 0);

        /**
         * First texture map
         */
        // Set the active texture0 unit to texture unit 0.
        GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);

        // Bind the texture to this unit.
        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTextureDataHandle0);

        // Set the sampler texture unit to 0, where we have saved the texture.
        GLES20.glUniform1i(mTextureUniformHandle0, 0);

        // Draw the triangle
        GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, indices.length,
            GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, drawListBuffer);

        // Disable vertex array
        GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
        GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(mTextureCoordinateHandle);
    }

    private String getVertexShader() {
        return RawResourceReader.readTextFileFromRawResource(mContext, R.raw
                ._vertex_shader);
    }

    private String getFragmentShader() {
        return RawResourceReader.readTextFileFromRawResource(mContext,     R.raw._fragment_shader);
    }

    private void constructVertex(){
        float with = getScreenWidth();
        float heigh = getScreenHeight();

        vertices = new float[]{
           0.0f,0.0f,-1.0f,
           with,0.0f,-1.0f,
           with,heigh,-1.0f,
           0.0f,heigh,-1.0f
        };
    }


    public void SetupImage()
    {
        constructVertex();
        // The vertex buffer.
        ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.length * 4);
        bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        vertexBuffer = bb.asFloatBuffer();
        vertexBuffer.put(vertices);
        vertexBuffer.position(0);

        // initialize byte buffer for the draw list
        ByteBuffer dlb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(indices.length * 2);
        dlb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        drawListBuffer = dlb.asShortBuffer();
        drawListBuffer.put(indices);
        drawListBuffer.position(0);

        // The texture buffer
        ByteBuffer uvsbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(uvs.length * 4);
        uvsbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        uvBuffer = uvsbb.asFloatBuffer();
        uvBuffer.put(uvs);
        uvBuffer.position(0);

        // Load the texture
        mTextureDataHandle0 = TextureHelper.loadTexture(mContext,     R.raw.bg_fine_day);
    }

    private  int getScreenWidth() {
        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager)     mContext.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        int width = wm.getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();// 屏幕宽度
        return width;
    }

    private  int getScreenHeight() {
        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager)     mContext.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        int height = wm.getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();// 屏幕高度
        return height;
    }
}
```

I don't know why.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Is the texture not showing up? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: I am terribly sorry that I can not upload the picture.There is no error  message.The problem is that the background can not completely display.Only display a part of it，bottom right part.if you can visit the website.you can see the effect.http://ask.csdn.net/questions/200422

Comment: I updated your question with the images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When looking at the uv-coordinates and the vertex coordinates, one can see that they do not fit together:

```
     vertex                    
----------------------------------------------
0.0f,0.0f,-1.0f,               0.0f, 0.0f,
with,0.0f,-1.0f,               0.0f, 1.0f,     <-- vertex: change in x, uv: change in y
with,heigh,-1.0f,              1.0f, 1.0f,
0.0f,heigh,-1.0f               1.0f, 0.0f
```

In addition, you tell OpenGL in this line:

```
GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mTextureCoordinateHandle, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0,
uvBuffer);                                             ^
```

that you have 3 uv-coordinates per vertex, but you only have 2.

Comment: Thanks BDL,Now the background is displayed normally.but the direction is wrong.the bitmap now turn upside down？

Comment: Then switch the zeros and the ones in the y-axis of the uv-coordinates

Comment: The problem is solved perfectly,I have two question about this problem.

Comment: If this problem is solved, please accept the answer. For the other questions, I would suggest you open a new question.

Comment: The problem is solved perfectly,I have two question about this problem.The first one: how can i know the uv-coordinate and vertex coordinates fit together ? I thought it's bijection between the  vertex and uv,for example (0,0) of vertex to (0,0) of uv,and (width,0) of vertex to (1,0),and (0,height) of vertex to (0,1) of uv.but the thought is wrong.     The second question: How can i know the second param of glVertexAttribPointer method? why should we set 2 in this case? Please help me, BDL,Thanks very much.

Comment: 2. is easy :) Its the number of floats that this attribute has. If you pass a vec2, it is 2, vec3 -> 3 ...

Comment: Ad 1.) The mapping is bijective but with respect to the used coordinate system. Texture always have the origin at the lower-left corner. depending on the projection used, the origin in the frame can be on the top-left corner, which flips the texture.

Comment: follow your suggestion,I have opened a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32025683/make-a-detailed-inquiry-to-the-answer-android-opengl-2-0